# Joomla Login Module Keeps Redirect to Landing Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, kunena

I have a simple problem but it's making me headache. So here it is, I have a landing page named index.html so that my Joomla can view a nice landing page instead visitor going to the default Joomla index.php

I also have a joomla kunena forum login module too so that users can login and logout immediately to the kunena forum from joomla's index.php. It works perfectly fine in /forum , /news, /about or others. But I have found out that it never works in /index.php

So whenever the visitor goes to [www.majapahit-mp.com/index.html](http://www.majapahit-mp.com/index.html) -> [www.majapahit-mp.com/index.php](http://www.majapahit-mp.com/index.php) -> then login on kunena login module in sidebar -> the visitor automatically gets to the landing page again and Not signed in.

I have not found yet a solution to this. Any suggestions is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole point of having a Joomla template is to make a nice looking page. Why don't you just make your home page in Joomla look like you want your home page to look?  You set the default home page in the joomla menu manager.  There is no "default" page in the way it sounds like you mean except that one page has been selected in your menu manage when you install. Are you sue the login module doesn't have a field to select the redirect page?